# Java - Counting words, lines, and characters from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to read in words from a file. I need to count the words, lines, and characters in the text file. The word count should only include words (containing only alphabetic letters, no punctuation, spaces, or non-alphabetic characters). The character count should only include the characters inside those words.

This is what I have so far. I'm unsure of how to count the characters. Every time I run the program, it jumps to the catch mechanism as soon as I enter the file name (and it should have no issues with the file path, as I've tried using it before). I tried to create the program without the try/catch to see what the error was, but it wouldn't work without it.

Why is it jumping to the catch function when I enter the file name? How can I fix this program to properly count words, lines, and characters in the text file?

Comment: What is your definition of a word?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Updated to (containing only alphabetic letters, no punctuation, spaces, or non-alphabetic characters)

Comment: That's one of the issues I'm having, it jumps straight to the exception and I cannot run the program unless the exception is present

Comment: I don't know if I should be using a string tokenizer, input stream, buffer reader, etc or what

Comment: Are you sure the user is entering a proper filename?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance yes, it has worked in previous programs

Comment: to be honest I would go for a much simpler way of reading byte-by-byte and checking the character's ascii value

Comment: Also when catching exceptions do `ex1.printStackTrace ();` - it will give you a lot more useful information

Comment: I tried your program and it did not give me any exception. Can you post contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get any exception with your code if I give a proper file name. As for reading the number of character, you should modify the logic a little bit. Instead of directly concatenating the number of words count, you should create a new instance of `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tempo, "[ .,:;()?!]+");` and iterate through all the token and sum the length of each token. This should give you the number of characters. Something like below

```
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            lineC++;
            tempo = fileScan.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tempo, "[ .,:;()?!]+");
            wordC += st.countTokens();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String stt = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println(stt); // Displaying string to confirm that like is splitted as I expect it to be
                charC += stt.length();
            }
            System.out.println("Lines: " + lineC + "\nWords: " + wordC+" \nChars: "+charC);
        }
```

**Note:** Escaping character with `StringTokenizer` will not work. i.e. you would expect that `\\s` should delimit with any whitespace character but it will instead delimit based on literal character `s`. If you want to escape a character, I suggest you to use `java.util.Pattern` and `java.util.Matcher`  and use it `matcher.find()` to idenfity words and characters

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but I didn't receive any exception here. However, I suspect that when you input the file name, maybe you forgot the extension of the file.

Answer (score -1):

You probably forgot the file extension while giving input, but there is a much simpler way of doing this. You also mention you don't know how to count the characters. You can try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class WordCount
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

       try {
            // Input file
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file.");
            String content = Files.readString(Path.of("C:/Users/garre/OneDrive/Desktop/" + userInput.next()));
            System.out.printf("Lines: %d\nWords: %d\nCharacters: %d",content.split("\n").length,Stream.of(content.split("[^A-Za-z]")).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty()).count(),content.length());
            }


        catch (IOException ex1) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

## Going through the code

```
import java.util.stream.*;
```

Note we use the streams package, for filtering out empty strings while finding words. Now let's skip forward a bit.

```
String content = Files.readString(Path.of("C:/Users/garre/OneDrive/Desktop/" + userInput.next()));
```

The above part gets all of the text in the file and stores it as a string.

```
System.out.printf("Lines: %d\nWords: %d\nCharacters: %d",content.split("\n").length,Stream.of(content.split("[^A-Za-z]")).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty()).count(),content.length());
```

Okay, this is a long line. Let's break it down.

`"Lines: %d\nWords: %d\nCharacters: %d"` is a format string, where each `%d` is replaced with the corresponding argument in the `printf` function. The first `%d` will be replaced by `content.split("\n").length`, which is the number of lines. We get the number of lines by splitting the string.

The second `%d` is replaced by `Stream.of(content.split("[^A-Za-z]")).filter(x -> !x.isEmpty()).count()`. `Stream.of` creates a stream from an array, and the array is an array of strings after you split on anything that is non-alphabetic (you said words are anything that are non-alphabetic). Next, we filter all the empty values out, since `String.split` keeps in empty values. The `.count()` is self-explanatory, takes the amount of words left after filtering.

The third and last `%d` is the simplest. It is replaced by the length of the string. `content.length()` should be self-explanatory.

I left your `catch` block intact, but I feel like the `System.exit(0)` is a bit redundant.